# Counting Number of Comparisons for MergeSort Java

Tags: java, mergesort

## I am having trouble counting the number of comparisons for mergesort in Java. Below is my code. Not sure if I'm placing it in the wrong spot, etc.

Any help is definitely appreciated, thanks.

```
private static int merge(int[] intArray, int first, int n1, int n2) {
    int numComparisons = 0;
        int[] temp = new int[n1+n2];
        int copied = 0, copied1 = 0, copied2 = 0;
        while((copied1 < n1) && (copied2 < n2)){
            if (intArray[first + copied1] < intArray[first + n1 + copied2]) {
                temp[copied++] = intArray[first + copied1++];
            }
            else {
                temp[copied++] = intArray[first + n1 + copied2++];
            }

        }

        while(copied1 < n1)     {
            temp[copied++] = intArray[first + copied1++];
        }
        while(copied2 < n2)     {
            temp[copied++] = intArray[first + n1 +copied2++];
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < n1+n2; i++) {
            numComparisons++;
            intArray[first + i] = temp[i];  
        }

        return numComparisons;
    }


    public static int mergeSortComparisons(int[] intArray, int first, int last){
        int n1, n2;
        if (last > 1){

            n1 = last/2;
            n2 = last - n1;

            mergeSortComparisons(intArray, first, n1);
            mergeSortComparisons(intArray, first + n1, n2);

            merge(intArray, first, n1, n2);
        }

        return first;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the number of comparisons, take the comparison step, refactor it to a method, and instrument the method.  You are incrementing `numComparisons` in the wrong place.

```
private static boolean lessThan(int[] ia, int leftIndex, int rightIndex) {
    numComparisons++;
    return ia[leftIndex] < ia[rightIndex];
}
```

Use that instead of your comparison line near the top of `merge`.

Also, write JUnit tests to ensure that your sort works.  Finally, do you need to have all your methods be static?

Comment: Where would I put it in my current function? My teacher isn't letting us do seperate functions for this. @eric-jablow

Comment: Then, insert `numComparisons++` right above the if statement, since that's the only place where you are actually comparing two entries.  The current location serves to count the number of times integers are moved, which isn't what you need.